# SELinux Enforcing is preventing logging into another user account?

Tags: selinux

I am using Debian 6 with SELinux enabled.

After enabling "enforcing" mode in SElinux, I have tried to login into another user account by 'login' command. But, I have been restricted by selinux.

### Terminal Screen:

```
debian:~# id -Z
root:sysadm_r:sysadm_t
debian:~# login Test_Unix_User
Password: 
Linux debian 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Tue Mar 8 21:36:00 UTC 2011 i686

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Would you like to enter a security context? [N]  N
Authentication failure
```

So, I have tried to capture and compile audit log using audit2allow.
But, while installing .pp file, I have got the following error.

### .pp installing error message:

```
debian:~# semodule -i loginSecurityContextProblemAuditLog.pp
libsepol.check_assertion_helper: neverallow violated by allow sysadm_t scsi_generic_device_t:chr_file { write };
libsemanage.semanage_expand_sandbox: Expand module failed
semodule:  Failed!
```

Why am I being prevented from logging into another account, even if I am in root account?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled PAM in linux and security context wont be asked at bootup.

Comment the following line in "/etc/pam.d/login" file.

session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open